# HTML 5 FlowPlayer

Tags: php, html, html5-video, flowplayer, video-player

I am using html5 flowplayer in my website to play videos, but I got below error:

- Playing file with size 4MB, it works
- Playing file with size over 4MB, it shows 'waiting...' for some seconds and shows error: HTML 5: video file not found.

System information:
 - My website is using Yii Framework
 - Server linux, Ram: 1GB

Here is code rendering player

```
$("#player").flowplayer({
     playlist: [
                   [
                         { mp4: $("#fileNameUpload").val() }  
                   ]
               ]
          });
```

Answer (score -1):

please check if your Framework might limit the file upload size:

[yiiframework Doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator#maxSize-detail)

Additionally PHP might have a limit there too.

[php.net manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

my own flowplayer only shows "video not found" when it was unable to read them so you might want to check that the file exists on your server in the first place.